# unittest says the continue statement is not being tested?

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest, coverage.py

Python 2.7.18 with Coverage 5.3 (client requirement)

Really stumped with this one. Trying to get the unit tests to report 100% before starting refactoring.

In the code example below (greatly simplified of course), Coverage says the continue statement is not being checked!

```
class Test7(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_7(self):
        test7()

def test7():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if i > 0:
            if i > 1:
                print 'loop1 iteration = ' + str(i)
            continue
        if i == 0:
            print 'blah'
```

If I put in a print statement **above the continue**, it gets checked and has no issues!
'pass' doesn't do the same though... :(

I've tried many other iterations and cannot figure it out.

It has to be something basic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continue line is probably removed by the CPython peephole optimizer, so can not be covered.

Suggested refactoring to avoid that issue:

```
if i > 0:
    if i > 1:
        print 'loop1 iteration = ' + str(i)
elif i == 0:
    print 'blah'
```

Comment: Correct. This is an often-reported bug against coverage: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/198  But it's a limitation from CPython's optimizations.  More recent versions of Python don't have the same problem.